# Like button not working properly on site, stays depressed

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like, blogger

On **[my blog](http://www.basesandbaskets.com)** I added the like button to the end of the posts. I have had it installed for about seven months now and it still does not work properly. I added the Javascript SDK and then the appropriate code to my Blogger template (develops.facebook.com) and while it appears on the blog it does not work properly.

Basically, if you click "like" at the end of any post, it will appear in the person's newsfeed but NOT as the individual post. Instead, the generic homepage of "Bases and Baskets" appears in the newsfeed. The interesting thing is that even though the generic logo and blogger description appears, if you click the link itself it sends you directly to the appropriate page. Not sure why...but as you could imagine I would prefer it to work properly and show the article. Also, I want the image at the beginning of the post to appear rather than my Facebook page's profile picture (which you can see [here](http://www.facebook.com/basesandbaskets)).

Not only is this a problem, but if you click "like" at the end of any one article, the like button remains depressed for ALL posts on the site. For example if one "likes" article A, and ventures to article B, the like button at the end of article B is depressed. Furthermore, the "like" tally at the end of ALL articles is exactly the same (~615).

I can attach a couple pictures that hopefully help, as well.

This has been quite frustrating as you could imagine, and became even more so when I made a new blog, Left Coast Chronicle, recently and everything works! If anybody can help me fix this I will give you all of the info I have to help (email address, chat info, complete HTML template of my blog) if you need it.

Thank you so much!!

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/murIC.pngt is what appears in the newsfeed

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Kww6z.png is what appears if you click "like" on the website itself.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: omg...this page is **HUGE** to load!

Secondly: you have missed one important parameter in your like button: the **href** attribute.

Your script:

```
<fb:like font='' href='' layout='button_count' send='false' show_faces='false' width='450'></fb:like>
```

Solution:

```
<fb:like href='LINK_TO_BLOG_POST' layout='button_count' send='false' show_faces='false' width='450'></fb:like>
```

Otherwise, the like button will like the current site it sits on (which is - you guessed it - the home page `http://www.basesandbaskets.com/`)

Third: you have the `<div id='fb-root'></div>` before each like button. Please use this  only **ONCE**!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for the extremely late response, just read this now! But it didn't quite work. Also, the script that I have which you wrote is what I do have but I also have the EXACT same script with the href='' in my other blog (www.leftcoastchronicle.com). And it's working there...? I'm not sure where to go from there but the reason I have the tag you mentioned multiple times is probably because I added it to the post body in blogger template. The problem probably comes from some stuff that I added that was unnecessary. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps but here is the code that appears at the end of the post body: <data:post.body/>
<div>
<p>
</p>
</div>
<div id='fb-root'/><fb:like href='http://www.basesandbaskets.com/' layout='button_count' send='false' show_faces='false' width='450'/>

Comment: Also, is there a way I can get the button to **not** show up on my home page (www.basesandbaskets.com) and only on the post itself?